# Xamarin Forms - Daily event based on time for schedulled local daily notification

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, notifications

I'm looking for a way to send local daily notifications at a defined hour (defined by user in settings, which is a TimeStamp), and being able to open a ContentPage on click.

Already found those plugins who are more or less the sames, but as i understood they don't really do the job i need

https://github.com/EgorBo/Toasts.Forms.Plugin

https://github.com/edsnider/LocalNotificationsPlugin

https://github.com/aritchie/notifications

The "scheduled notif" looks like to work just once and not repeated.

The simplest way would be to trigger an event daily at desired time, then i could use the plugin with it by calling a "notification send" method each time the event is triggered.

I saw very long ways to do it with dependencies for Android and iOS separately, but would like to find a cross-plaftorm solution.
Or notifications are really that complicated to implement? I thought local ones it won't be such a pain.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Android, if your min Api <19, you can use [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html), and [here is a blog about AlarmManager](http://droidmentor.com/schedule-notifications-using-alarmmanager/),

> beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact.

If api>5.0, because there is Doze mode in Android, you need use [JobSchedule](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html).

If these not work on some Android devices.

Maybe [GCM Network Manager](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/network-manager) or [Firebase Job Dispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android#user-content-firebase-jobdispatcher-) will help you.

It will be more difficult to send local notification at a certain time interval in Android in the future.

Comment: API > 24, so i guess i can just use the last 2 ones you gave. But still it's only for android, not a cross platform solution. Or i can forget local notification and schedule only push ones

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I mean the min Api, if it is 16, you need integrate them.

Comment: [You can refer to this to add put notification  to your application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-push)

Comment: With your last link it will send notification to android and ios app at same time by just one action if i understood well?